# Find value from subsequent input and form a sentence

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

I have <sup>3</sup>/<sub>4</sub> input field and and some words between them.

like,

```
<div id="nl-form-0" > 
    Please remove stitch after 
      <input type="text" value="15" />
   days of discharge, i,e on 
     <input type="text" value="22/5/2016" />
     to improve your health in
     <input type="text" value="20" />
  days. 
</div>
```

I need output in a form like a sentence:

> "Please remove stitch after 15 days of discharge, i,e on 22/5/2016 to improve your health in 20 days."

Answer (score 2):

Edit:

Updated [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuu4ktj9/2/) now, Selected value in select will also be added:

Jquery Code:

```
var html = $("#nl-form-0").clone();
    html.find('input,select').each(function(){
        var cell = $(this);
        $(this).replaceWith(cell.val());
     })
    var main =html.html();
    main = main.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');
    alert(main);
```

Here is the answer, Checkout this [Jsfiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zuu4ktj9/1/):

Jquery Code:

```
var html = $("#nl-form-0").clone();
html.find('input').each(function(){
    var cell = $(this);
    $(this).replaceWith(cell.val());
 })
var main =html.html();
main = main.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');
alert(main);
```

Comment: Hi, what in case of if select dropdown will be there?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```js
var text = $('#nl-form-0').contents().map(function() {
  if (this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE && this.nodeValue.trim()) {
    return this.nodeValue.trim();
  } else if ($(this).is('input')) {
    return $(this).val()
  } else if ($(this).is('select')) {
    return $('option:selected', this).text()
  }
}).get().join(' ');

snippet.log(text)
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nl-form-0">
  Please remove stitch after
  <input type="text" value="15" />days of discharge, i,e on
  <input type="text" value="22/5/2016" />to improve your health in
  <input type="text" value="20" />days. also
  <select>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2" selected>Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, what in case of if select dropdown will be there?

Comment: @chang change `$(this).is('input')` to `$(this).is('input,select')`

Comment: actually option's value is diff than text. so i did " else if ($(this).is('select')) {
    return $(this).text()
  } " but it returns text of all options. not selected one

Comment: and also can't make option value and text same as val is dependant id

Answer (score 0):

this works perfectely

```js
var text = $('#nl-form-0').contents().map(function() {
  if (this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE && this.nodeValue.trim()) {
    return this.nodeValue.trim();
  } else if ($(this).is('input')) {
    return $(this).val()
  }
}).get().join(' ');

snippet.log(text)
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nl-form-0">
  Please remove stitch after
  <input type="text" value="15" />days of discharge, i,e on
  <input type="text" value="22/5/2016" />to improve your health in
  <input type="text" value="20" />days.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this. More clean(pure js, so optimized than jQuery) and simple way to do the same. [Tested on Chrome]

```js
function myFunction() {
 var div = document.getElementById('test');
 var children = div.childNodes;
 var sentence = "";

 for (var i=0; i < children.length; i++) {
  var child = children[i];

  if (child.value) {
   sentence += child.value;
  }
  else {
   sentence += child.data;
  }
 }

 document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = sentence;
}
```

```html
<div id="test" > 
    Please remove stitch after 
      <input type="text" value="15" />
   days of discharge, i,e on 
     <input type="text" value="22/5/2016" />
     to improve your health in
     <input type="text" value="20" />
  days. 
</div>

<span id="output"></span>
<input type="button" value="Click me" onclick="myFunction()"></input>
```

Comment: Hi, what in case of if select dropdown will be there?